# Is there a name for the function $\max(x, 0)$?

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a name for the function $ \max(x, 0) $?

For comparison, the function $ \max(x, -x) $ is known as the *absolute value* or *modulus* of x, and has its own notation $ |x| $.

Comment: should there be a name for this function? is it important enough to get its own name? is it used often enough to warrant an abbreviation? does it capture something so profound to be worth naming? If you answer any of these question positively, then you can improve your question.

Comment: In finance `max(x-s,0)` is the payoff of a call option where s is the strike price and x is the price of the underlying stock on the expiry date.

Comment: The question asks for the name of the operation, not an example of something that is computed using it. The operation $\max(x,0)$ isn't called "payoff of a call option", just as the operation of multiplication isn't called "force", despite Newton's second law.

Comment: @ColonelPanic - a notation that is frequently used for the payoff of a call option is $(x-s)_{+}$, especially in actuarial science.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is called the [*positive part*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts) of the real number $x$, and often denoted by $x^+$.

Likewise, the *negative part* of $x$ is $x^-=\max\{-x,0\}$ and the pair of nonnegative real numbers $(x^+,x^-)$ is fully characterized by the pair of identities $$x=x^+-x^-,\qquad\lvert x\rvert=x^++x^-.$$

Comment: It should be noted that the negative part is, in fact, a positive number.  For example the negative part of -3 is 3.

Comment: Indeed the positive part and the negative part are both nonnegative numbers.

Comment: Similarly, the imaginary part of a complex number is a real number.

Comment: I would rather call this the "positive part of the identity function", because the "positive part" definition as you cite it refers to functions and not numbers.

Comment: @example Thanks for your input. It just happens that this (i.e., the positive part of the real number $x$) is what mathematicians call it (i.e., $\max(x,0)$).

Answer (score 20):

Wikipedia calls this the [ramp function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function) and notes that it can be written using [Macaulay brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaulay_brackets).

> $ \{x\} = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ x, & x \ge 0. \end{cases} $

Answer (score 16):

Since this is a math site, not a programming site, my answer may or may not be regarded as trivia. Anyway...

In computer graphics this function is called [**clamping**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_%28graphics%29). The general form is $\mathrm{clamp(x, lowerBound, upperBound)}$ and is defined as

```
function clamp(x, lowerBound, upperBound):
  if(x < lowerBound)
    return lowerBound
  else if(x > upperBound)
    return upperBound
  else
    return x
```

or $\mathrm{min( max(x, lowerBound), upperBound)}$.

$\max(x,0)$ is the special case $\mathrm{clamp}(x, 0, +\infty)$.

The clamping function is ubiquitous in computer graphics: You often need to confine a calculated value (e.g. a color intensity) into a range of valid values (e.g. $[0,1]$ or $[0,255]$).

Comment: What language is this? Javascript?

Comment: @Joao: it looks to be pseudocode; it is neither JavaScript nor Python.

Comment: @Reid Ohhh! Thank you!

Comment: It looks like Java, only `function` is not Java. Replacing `function` with something like `public static int` makes it Java, a method to be inserted in some class.

Comment: It's pseudocode.

Comment: It's pseudocode and can trivially easily be translated into Python, JS or anything else. @OutlawLemur It's not literal Python because of a few minor differences: a) `function clamp(...)` instead of `def clamp(...):` b) No colons at the end of the if/elif/else lines c) Conditional expressions enclosed by parentheses `if(x < lowerBound)` instead of `if x < lowerBound:`

Comment: @MickG Even if you replaced `function` with `public static int`, it would still be a long way away from being Java.

Comment: Not that long: put semicolons at the end of the instructions, an open brace instead of the colon, a closed brace at the end, and then it must be put in a class, but is otherwise Java.

Comment: @MickG: It is much closer to Python than Java.

Comment: @MickG The real problem here is the user mistaking the (tip of the iceberg of the) syntax for the language. Your reasoning misses the foundations of Java (such as strong typing and object-orientation) and the whole point of pseudocode. Even with modifications that made it compile (with yours it wouldn't), the code would be no more Java than C, C++, C#, Javascript and any one of the thousands languages that share the braced syntax with if/else and return - which is a negligible fraction of the syntax.

Comment: @MickG Adding braces and semicolons and putting it in a class still wouldn't make it valid Java code. So yes, as ignis says, there is no sense in calling this "almost Java" and no reason to do so. It's pseudocode, plain and simple.

Answer (score 12):

You can check that:

$$\color{blue}{\max(x,0) = x \, H(x)}$$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside or unit step function. A name for this? Not a clue, but hope it helps.

Comment: This is actually a pretty nice implementation. For example, here's a quick and dirty computation of the derivative for $x \neq 0$: $$\frac{d}{dx} \max(x,0) = \frac{d}{dx} H(x)\cdot x = H(x) \frac{d}{dx} x = H(x) \cdot 1 = H(x).$$ It works because $H(x)$ is basically a constant. More precisely, the function $$\begin{cases} 1 & x>0 \\ 0 & x < 0\end{cases}$$ is a locally constant openly-supported partial functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is exactly what you need in order to treat it as a constant insofar as differentiation is concerned.

Answer (score 10):

I have heard this function called the [rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)). This is a pretty exclusive field name though, and I wouldn't expect to see it anywhere outside of neural networks.

Comment: I think the use in neural networks derives from the use of the term in electrical engineering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier

Comment: @A.Donda Thanks for the information.

Comment: This might be a newer coinage than when this answer was originally written, but as of 2021 the term "ReLU" (for rectified linear unit) is also frequently used for this function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

$$f(x) = \frac{x + |x|}{2}$$

Comment: I suppose that's interesting, but it's not at all what the question is asking.

Comment: The point is that the function doesn't need a name, it can be expressed in terms of $|x|$ and $x$.

Comment: So squaring doesn't need a name because it can be expressed in terms of $x$ and $2$? And factorial doesn't need a name because it can be expressed in terms of product? And...

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's not about that. We call $x^2$ squaring but we don't have a name for $x^2+3$. We have a name for $n!$ but not one for $(-1)^nn!$. So perhaps a name for the function described is not really needed. It turns out it does have a name, but if it didn't and you needed to use it in a paper, for instance you can just give it a special letter and define it at the beggining of the paper and it would be ok.

Comment: How is `(x+|x|)/2` better then `max(x, 0)` anyway?

Comment: @DarthGeek "we don't have a name for $x^2+3$." So what? The question is asking if there's a name for $\max(x,0)$. The fact that some arbitrary polynomial doesn't have a name has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby DarthGeek has a point.  Just like $x^2 + 3$ doesn't need a name because you can express it in terms of simpler functions, likewise for most purposes it would be in bad style to give a special name to the function $\frac{|x| + x}{2}$.  As it turns out, there are some cases (in particular in measure theory) where the positive part $x^+$ and negative part $x^-$ are very important, and are fundamentally a part of the theory you are working with, so in those cases you give them a name.  But unless the OP is doing measure theory or otherwise using the positive part in a (contd)

Comment: (contd) fundamental way, the OP should stick with $\frac{|x| + x}{2}$.  As a thought experiment, imagine the question was, "is there a name for the function $2|x| + |x^2| + 3$?" and it turned out that someone had given this function a name in a paper once.  A good answer would not direct the OP to the function's name, but would rather explain that this function does not need a name.