# what does this notation exactly mean? $(x)_{+}$

Tags: notation

So the question is already given in the title: 
I see in some mathematics proof, the following notation is used:

$x=(z)_+$

and we know that $x$ should be greater than or equal to zero, i.e. $x\geq 0$.

So does this notation mean if $z<0$ then $x=0$?

Comment: This is not a standard notation. Where did you see it?

Comment: in a linear algebra note, lagrangian dual stuff

Comment: Left and right maybe?

Comment: In some areas, $(z)_+:=\max(z,0)$, cf. for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/898156/145682) answer.