# What is a minus in top index after closing brace?

Tags: analysis, statistics

I cam across a piece of math with something I have never seen before:

$$\left(R_t-\overline R\right)^-$$

Is there any chance you could help me understand how should I treat this "minus" sign in the top index after the closing brace?

Thank you

Both $R_t$ and $R$ are regular floating point numbers.

I am not sure if it will help, but the straigtt translation would be:

negative deviation from the mean

The whole thing:

SV=$\sum_{t=0}^m\left(\left(R_t-\overline R\right)^-\right)^2$

$R_t$ is the rate of return

$\overline R$ is the average rate of return

I just don't know what that - is :/

Comment: The MathJax is `(R_t-\overline{R})^{-}`. Without more context I’ve no idea what is meant here, I’m afraid.

Comment: How to write it is straight forward enough: `(R)^-` gives $(R)^-$.

Comment: @Krystian: Where did you come across these symbols?

Comment: @Moritz - this comes from wallet analytics and management, some kind of class in our local university of economy. Unfortunately I came across this way too late to get an "official" answer from university and none of the peers were able to help me "look it up on the internet" they say. Not my classes mind you, I'm just a friend in need. This one is used to calculate deviation of rate of return.

Comment: @Krystian: it looks to me like some sort of "average"-value (e,g,, arithmetic mean). Does this make sense?

Comment: @Moritz yep, exactly, but I have no idea what that "-" means. This is a part of the equation, I've probably made a mistake not to put the whole thing, but I wanted to be precise. I will type it down.

Comment: $$x^-=\max(-x,0)$$

Comment: @Did Does this mean that $-1^- = -1$ and $1^- = 0$?

Comment: @Krystian: I think that Did is right. It means, that if your difference is negative, you take $0$ instead. Consider $-1^- = 0$ and $1^- = 1$.

Comment: @Mortiz are you sure? $-(-1) > 0$  am i missing something? $-1^- = max(-(-1), 0) = -1$  right?

Comment: ?? Why not read what I wrote? $(2)^-=0$, $(-3)^-=3$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts (But I find surprising that the text does not define the notation.)

Comment: @Did sorry for the misunderstanding on my part and thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898149/is-there-a-name-for-the-function-maxx-0/898156#898156